# What does LFNO and LF stands for?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am parsing Java with Antlr, using ready Java9 grammar from [antlr-grammars repo](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java/java9).

In the Antlr contexts I often see methods with "lfno" or "lf" suffics in the name, for instance:

`classInstanceCreationExpression_lfno_primary`

`arrayAccess_lfno_primary`,

or even like this - `PrimaryNoNewArray_lfno_primary_lf_arrayAccess_lfno_primaryContext`

I wonder what does that mean, because I coundn't find any information on that

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Note that a parser rule can be named pretty much anything. And the answer was also asked on ANTLR's Github issue tracker: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/issues/1026 that did not result in a definitive answer, which leads me to believe the name has no real significant meaning.

Comment: I never understood that myself. But the rules were introduced in order to eliminate mutual left recursion in the rules derived from the language spec.